# pandas - select/mask the first n elements by value

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from one single dataframe:

```
I,a,b,c,d,e,f
A,1,3,5,6,4,2
B,3,4,7,1,0,0
C,1,3,5,2,0,7
```

I would like to keep/mask the first three elements in the rows by value keeping the order of the columns, so that the resulting dataframe appears as:

```
I,a,b,c,d,e,f
A,0,0,5,6,4,0
B,3,4,7,0,0,0
C,0,3,5,0,0,7
```

So far I've been able to sort the dataframe with:

```
a = df.values
```

and

```
a.sort(axis=1)
```

so that:

```
[[1 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 0 1 1 3 4]
 [0 1 1 3 5 7]]
```

obtaining a sorted numpy array, loosing information about the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rank the values row-wise and then filter them and call `fillna`:

```
In [248]:
df[df.rank(axis=1, method='min')>3].fillna(0)

Out[248]:
   I  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  0  0  0  5  6  4  0
1  0  3  4  7  0  0  0
2  0  0  3  5  0  0  7
```

You can then concat this back to get the 'I' column back:

```
In [268]:
pd.concat([df['I'], df[df.rank(axis=1, method='min')>3].fillna(0)[df.columns[1:]]], axis=1)

Out[268]:
   I  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  A  0  0  5  6  4  0
1  B  3  4  7  0  0  0
2  C  0  3  5  0  0  7
```

Output from intermediate dfs:

```
In [269]:

df.rank(axis=1, method='min')
Out[269]:
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  3  5  6  4  2
1  4  5  6  3  1  1
2  2  4  5  3  1  6
In [270]:

df.rank(axis=1, method='min')>3
Out[270]:
       a      b     c      d      e      f
0  False  False  True   True   True  False
1   True   True  True  False  False  False
2  False   True  True  False  False   True
```

Comment: Thanks Ed! Again! Actually setting index_col='I' when reading allows to avoid the concat!

Comment: so you're after `df[df.rank(axis=1, method='min')<=3].fillna(0)`?

Comment: Sorry Ed, I've just realized...what I meant was keeping the three highest values of the dataframe, not values over 3.

Comment: but for your specifc shape df that's what my code does, if your real df is a different shape then you'd need to do something like `df.rank(axis=1, method='min')>df.shape[1] - 3`

Comment: With `df[df.rank(axis=1, method='min')<=3].fillna(0)` I'm getting again the values <= 3... what I would like to keep are the first n sorted values, no matter the values.

Comment: The code is comparing the rank, not the values so it shouldn't be difficult to modify to work for your df

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I had to select n first truth values from a **pd.Series** object to use them as a mask to modify values in a **pd.DataFrame**. This is how I solved it

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['alligator', 'bee', 'falcon', 'lion',
                    'monkey', 'parrot', 'shark', 'whale', 'zebra']})
ser = pd.Series([True,False,False,True,False,True])
df.loc[ser.nlargest(n=2).index, "animal"] = "new animal"
print(df)
       animal
0  new animal
1         bee
2      falcon
3  new animal
4      monkey
5      parrot
6       shark
7       whale
8       zebra
```